# JSF + Tomcat losing CSS

Tags: java, css, jsf, tomcat

I'm using JSF 2.2, Netbeans 7.4, Primefaces 3.5 Tomcat 7 and Hibernate 3.6.10.

I'm migrating a web project that is finished and works great from normal libraries and glassfish 3.1.2 TO maven and Tomcat 7.0.41.0.

Initially everything seems to work fine, the main page starts ok and it can be viewed perfectly with all his CSS and so on, but when I press any of the links to go to another section ALL CSS seems to get lost (even the primefaces style).

The navigation continues working ok but no CSS is applied.

There's an error in the Tomcat console:

```
Grave: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [Faces Servlet] en el contexto con ruta [/AuPair] lanzó la excepción [javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config] con causa raíz
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
```

I have searched about this error over the net with no result and I don't know if it is related or not with my problem.

I'm using templates like this:

```
<html lang="#{sesion.idiomaActual.country}"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

 <f:view>
    <h:head>
        <link href="CSS/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>           
        <ui:composition template="/plantilla.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="cabecera">
                <ui:include src="cabecera_vista.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="contenido">
                <ui:include src="index_vista.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="pie">
                <ui:include src="pie_vista.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>        
    </h:body>
  </f:view>
</html>
```

This is the first page shown "index_vista" (firstly appears ok, but if you leave and come back it doesn't):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <f:view locale="#{sesion.idiomaActual}">
    <h:head>
        <link href="CSS/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>           
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>            
            <div id="inicio" class="area_contenido"> 
                <br/>                                
                <p:imageSwitch effect="fade"  styleClass="galeria_fotos">  
                    <ui:repeat value="#{index_controlador.listafotos}" var="image">  
                        <p:graphicImage value="/Imagenes/#{image}" />  
                    </ui:repeat>  
                </p:imageSwitch> 

                <p:fieldset legend="#{msjs.inicio_tit1}" styleClass="panel_inicio" >   
                    <p:graphicImage value="/Imagenes/inicio1.jpg" styleClass="imagen_panel_inicio1"/>  
                    <h:outputText styleClass="texto_panel_inicio" escape="false" value="#{msjs.inicio_text1}" />                     
                </p:fieldset>  

                <p:fieldset legend="#{msjs.inicio_tit2}" styleClass="panel_inicio" >                       
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputText styleClass="texto_panel_inicio" escape="false" value="#{msjs.inicio_text2}" />

                    <p:graphicImage value="/Imagenes/inicio2.jpg" styleClass="imagen_panel_inicio2" alt="Foto Apreton manos"/>  
                </p:fieldset>  

                <p:fieldset legend="#{msjs.inicio_tit3}" styleClass="panel_inicio" >   
                    <p:graphicImage value="/Imagenes/inicio3.jpg" styleClass="imagen_panel_inicio3"/>  
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputText styleClass="texto_panel_inicio" escape="false" value="#{msjs.inicio_text3}"  />                     
                </p:fieldset>  

            </div>         
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
  </f:view> 
</html>
```

This is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jesus</groupId>
<artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>XXX</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>redmond</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>           
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
        <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The project structure is this:

http://i61.tinypic.com/2h3sfmo.jpg

I'm a beginner with Tomcat, can anyone help me with that? 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem my own.
Tomcat doesn't work with relative paths and Glassfish does.
So instead of using:

```
<link href="CSS/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Use this:

```
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/CSS/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="CSS" name="estilos.css"  />
```

Comment: Hi! I'm afraid that I have already tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check if css file is loaded in the browser?

Comment: The first time that the first page loads the "estilos.CSS" file is loaded with 50 rules (mozilla firefox style editor), but whenever I navigate to another page the file is not loaded anymore (0 rules). The curious point about it is that when I select the "estilos.CSS" in the style editor menu appears the HTML code of the error webpage "error.xhtml". So I suppose that the CSS location is lost. Any idea about what is happening?